# Taking the antilog of every cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of data that is presented in log format, I need to be able to change this in order to upload it.  I seem to keep running into errors related to cell contents being read as a string instead of a double.

I have tried several variations of the code below (using ^ and power).  The closest I have been able to get is to have every cell fill with the formula itself instead of the answer.  The variable c is loaded correctly and other formulas appear to work.

```
Dim c As Range

Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In Range("A2 :A" & Lastrow)
   c = c.Power(10, c)
    Next
End Sub
```

or

```
Function Antilog(rwDest As Range)
Dim c As Range
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In Range("A2" & Lastrow)
         c.Value = "=10^ c.Value"
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: `c.Value = 10 ^ c.Value`

Comment: also this `Range("A2" & Lastrow)` is one cell at row 2 + whatever last row is, not a range from row 2 to the lastrow.  You need: ``Range("A2:A" & Lastrow)`

Comment: Thank you! That worked, I could have sworn that that was the first thing I tried.  The second range was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Avoid a Loop Using `Worksheet.Evaluate`

```vb
Sub AntiLog()
        
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If it's the workbook containing this code, use 'ThisWorkbook' instead.
    
    ' Reference the single-column range.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    
    ' Use 'Worksheet.Evaluate'...
    rg.Value = ws.Evaluate("10^" & rg.Address)
    'rg.Value = ws.Evaluate("IFERROR(10^" & rg.Address & ","""")")
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of worksheet.Evaluate. Is there a benefit to avoiding a loop using this?

Comment: Of course, there is: It's more efficient (faster). Fill column `A` with e.g. 10 thousand cells containing `=RANDBETWEEN(1,10)`, copy/paste values and make a backup copy in column `B`. Now run your code. Your code will take about 2s. Now copy/paste from `B` to `A` and run my code. You'll see the difference. Looping through each cell is the slowest way and you should avoid it whenever possible.